# aframe raycaster not registering in browser

Tags: aframe

I try to work with a raycaster, but i can't seem te get it to work(nothing shows in my console). I tried the example on: https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/raycaster.html

Javascript file

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
 dependencies: ['raycaster'],
 init: function () {
      this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function () {
     console.log('Player hit something!');
    });
   }   
 });
```

index.html

```
<a-scene>
 <a-entity id="player" collider-check>
   <a-entity raycaster="objects: .collidable" position="0 -0.9 0"  rotation="90 0 0"></a-entity>
 </a-entity>
 <a-entity class="collidable" geometry="primitive: box" position="1 0 0"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I try to walk in al possible directions and nothing shows in my console. I run my code in google chrome on a xampp server.

Hope someone can explain to me what is going on!

Comment: Any warnings in the console? Did you include stuff in order? (A-Frame JS, then components JS, then <a-scene>).

Comment: Sorry if i cant follow but can you specify what component.js is? Did i miss it???

Comment: Your JS pasted above

Comment: I followed the structure in the order above. When ShowLine is set to true the raycaster registers but fires 1000+ events.

Comment: I currently have a PR open in A-Frame to not re-fire intersected events if nothing has changed. So to only fire it once. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/3250

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure. Make sure the component is registered before the A-Frame HTML.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="collider-check.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity collider-check></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Till this date this question is not answerd. The example in the Aframe docs just dont seem to work?